# What are the tattvas of different entities (Gods,Devas,humans et al) under Srivaishnavism?

Tags: sri-vaishnava

Madhwists have a clearly laid out ranking of entities:

https://madhwafestivals.com/2016/08/27/taratamya/

I think the Srivaishnavite hierarchy is Vishnu, Lakshmi,Nitya Suris and all others.

Does Srivaishnavite scripture spell this out in detail?

In particular, which entities are allowed to enter Paramapadam or Vaikuntham?

Answer (score 0):

1. Para Tattva:

   - Bhagavad Gita (Chapter 10, Verse 20): "I am the Self, O Gudakesha, seated in the hearts of all creatures. I am the beginning, the middle, and the end of all beings."
   - Vishnu Purana (Book 1, Chapter 22): Descriptions of Lord Vishnu as the Supreme Reality.
2. Jiva Tattva:

   - Bhagavad Gita (Chapter 2, Verse 20): "For the soul, there is neither birth nor death at any time. He has not come into being, does not come into being, and will not come into being. He is unborn, eternal, ever-existing, and primeval."
3. Achit Tattva:

   - Bhagavad Gita (Chapter 13, Verse 27): "The soul (jiva) seated in the body is part of the eternal Godhead and is, therefore, neither born nor die, nor does it grow. This individual soul is indestructible and eternal."
4. Ishvara Tattva:

   - Vishnu Purana (Book 6, Chapter 7): Descriptions of Lord Vishnu as the Supreme Godhead and the controller of the universe.
5. Cit Tattva:

   - Taittiriya Upanishad (Brahmananda Valli, Verse 2): "Satyam Jnanam Anantam Brahman" - Brahman is Truth, Knowledge, and Infinite.
6. Prakriti Tattva:

   - Bhagavad Gita (Chapter 14, Verses 5-6): Descriptions of the three gunas - Sattva, Rajas, and Tamas - and their influence on beings.
7. Karma Tattva:

   - Bhagavad Gita (Chapter 4, Verse 17): "He who sees inaction in action, and action in inaction, is intelligent among men, and he is in the transcendental position, although engaged in all kinds of work."
8. Maya Tattva:

   - Srimad Bhagavatam (Canto 11, Chapter 14): Explanation of the illusory nature of the material world and how it binds the souls.

Only certain entities are allowed to enter Paramapadam based on their devotion and spiritual attainment. These entities are:

1. Nitya Suri: These are eternal liberated souls who reside in Vaikuntham and are in constant service of Lord Vishnu.
2. Mukta Jiva: Souls who have attained liberation through devotion to Lord Vishnu and have been freed from the cycle of birth and death.
3. Shri Vaishnava Acharyas: The spiritual preceptors and leaders within the Srivaishnavism tradition who have attained a high level of spiritual realization and are considered eligible to enter Vaikuntham.
4. Alvars: The twelve revered poet-saints of Srivaishnavism, who composed devotional hymns and were deeply devoted to Lord Vishnu.
5. Bhagavatas: Devotees of Lord Vishnu who have dedicated their lives to His worship and service, and have developed a profound love for Him.

Entry into Vaikuntham is not based on caste, creed, or social status but on one's devotion and surrender to Lord Vishnu. Srivaishnavism emphasizes the path of Bhakti (devotion) as the means to attain liberation and reach the divine abode of the Supreme Lord.

Comment: Are there citations from Srivaishnavite scripture? isn't there a category called "Baddha Jiva"? @nitesh